# Looping through each item in a single output, using Powershell

Tags: loops, powershell, match, output

currently I am trying to write a script that obtains a list of all services on my computer, then try to use each service name in that output to run "sc.exe qfailure [service]."

However, I am not sure why my output consistently runs a single service's name over and over again. Here is my code.

Also, I'm trying to make it that if any service is configured to run a program in it's recovery options, it should be able to print out the service name. I only know how to -match "RUN PROCESS" though. How can I match the service name?

Part of my code is below.

```
    $services = get-service | select -expand name;
    Write-Host $services
    $output = $services | ForEach {sc.exe qfailure $services in};
```

Will appreciate any help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pipe an object into foreach, each object within that object can be signified by the $_ variable

```
$output = $services | ForEach {sc.exe qfailure $_ in};
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask what the $_ stands for in definition? Also, how could I start on getting a service that has "run a program" configured to print it's name?

Comment: @J.Lim `$_` is a default variable that represents the current object read from the pipeline.